# How to skip one-time scripts whose entry is already present in RoundHouse.ScriptsRun table?

Tags: sql-server, roundhouse

We are in process of setting up ETL and Business Objects for our new client. The database strcuture for this new client would be same as of our old client. So, we have copied the database structure of old client.
We have also copied the entries/data in RoundHouse.ScriptsRun table.
As a part of ETL code deployment script, we also run DB upgrade script.
This DB upgrade script checks for the DB scripts from code base.

When the DB upgrade script is executed then we are getting error

> one time script has changed since last run. Please donot change one-time scripts once it is executed

Is there a way we can skip the execution of one-time scripts whose entries are already present in RoundHouse.ScriptsRun table?

Note:

1. The database structure that we copied has latest DB changes that we will be performing through one-time scripts. For the same reason, we want to skip the execution of one-time scripts
2. I tried executing the script using **--warnOnOneTimeScriptChanges=true** setting but it executes the scripts again which is causing discrepancy in our database structure

Comment: Why run any roundhouse scripts on your new database if it's automatically copying the structure of the old?

Comment: The ETL deployment process (.bat file) has a method that executes the scripts. Unfortunately, we cannot skip the method as it is part of the deployment process and every release we run the deployment process for clients

Comment: Then don't change your one time scripts and you won't get the error.

Comment: I have not changed anything in the script but still I am getting the error. That's why it's getting difficult for me to understand the issue.